# Why do the field line asymptotes in this diagram bend?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

If there is a +1 charge and another +1 charge the field lines have a vertical and horizontal asymptote.

However, when the charges are uneven, the vertical asymptote is curved leftwards:

[image: +3 charge and +1 charge]

I don't understand this. Surely using the inverse square law, as the distance from both charges increases the repulsive force from the greater charge should increase at a greater rate?

Comment: Can you please cite where this image comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You're making some strong claims about the asymptotic behaviour of the system from an awfully limited range in the spatial scale shown in the diagram.

Let's see what happens when we zoom out a bit:

[image]

In the actually-asymptotic regime (and setting aside a bunch of problems with the presentation defaults in Mathematica's StreamPlot function), the streamlines look pretty straight to me. (If you do things carefully, you will find that the field lines asymptotically approach straight lines radiating out from the center of charge of the system, so long as the total charge is nonzero.)

Comment: I agree with this solution. The picture in the OP is very misleading. In the end behavior, it should look like the electric field of a point particle with a charge equal to the sum of the original two charges.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was worded badly. My question was as to why the lines are not vertical and instead why they are diagonally pointing in the North West direction at the asymptote

Comment: @IK-_-IK [There **is** a field line that is asymptotically vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2btq5.png), with that asymptote going through the center of charge. The field lines to the left of that have asymptotic slopes that point to the left, precisely as you would expect. Otherwise, it's unclear to me what you mean by "the vertical asymptote", and you will need to be much more specific in what you're asking. (Perhaps you're asking why the asymptote that leaves the saddle-point vertically curves to the left? In that case: because there is no requirement at all that it do anything specific.)